# How to install Glade in Mac OSX Leopard

Tags: gtk, osx-leopard, glade

How can I install Glade in Mac OSX Leopard? I haven't found any guide that really helped me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using the [MacPorts package manager](http://www.macports.org/).

They have [several packages](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=glade) available for installing Glade (as well as libglade):

- Glade 2
- Glade 3
- Glade 3 unstable
- libglade
- libglade2

Answer (score 1):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install homebrew/x11/glade
```

Comment: I am porting a GTK program to OS X and found this gem.

Answer (score 0):

try before:

```
brew update
```

then

```
brew install homebrew/x11/glade
```

Comment: I don't think that improves on an earlier identical answer, which was not perfect in itself...